# Ordinal or Scale?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, ordinal-data, scales, psychology

I have collected data using two questionnaires for depression and eating habits - I have added together the variables for each construct and have one number for each variable for each participant.

Am I right in saying that now my data is interval? and carry out parametric testing
Or is still ordinal and I should carry out non-parametric tests?

help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't a straight forward answer. It'd depend on the range of the score, the distribution, and also partially how you see these two constructs.

If your final score has a pretty good range that allows the responses to spread out, then it'd fare better when used as a scale variable. On the contrary, if the score only allows for very litter number of attributes (e.g. correct answers in 3 nutrition questions, ranging from 0 to 3), then chance it may not fulfill many assumptions for parametric techniques.

If the distribution is highly skewed (e.g. a lot of people got full mark or near full mark in nutrition), then parametric techniques such as t-test or ANOVA can become challenging.

And lastly, how do you see the effect a "1 unit" increase in the score on the construct matters as well. If you do feel that regardless of where the base score is, one extra point would bring about similar change in the construct, then it could be analyzed as a scale.

If you feel that's too much control in your hand, try do some literature review on the scores that you're analyzing. (And I hope you're using validated scores that have been used and analyzed by other researchers.) Use a few to support your analytical decisions.

And lastly, if you're just making up your own scores (which I do not recommend, but alas) you can always check and report both of the methods. If your main conclusion does not change, the decision of treating it as ordinal or scale may not matter.